# convert raw video .y4m to mpg video with certain GOP

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to compress a raw video **.y4m** to **mpg**, and I want then to extract the frames from the mpg video, I need the GOP of the compression to be `:IBBPBBPBBPBBPBBIBBP....15:2`

I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.ym4 -vcodec libx264 -sameq -y -r 30 output.avi 2>list.txt
ffmpeg -i output.avi -vcodec libx264 -y -sameq -vf showinfo -y -f image2 image%3d.jpeg -r 30 2>list1.txt
```

The output contains only 2 I frames, `100 P` and `198 B` frames, it is not `15:2 GOP`, what to do?

I need one `I-frame` every 15 frames, and the pattern to b `IBBPBBP..`

Sorry, Im new to `ffmpeg`, please help me, this is the input to my project, it is the important step to me.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to force an exact pattern, however you can control the frequency of keyframes with these flags : -keyint_min
-sc_threshold
-g

Comment: sir can you help me how to use these flags, could you please insert them in my command, i need I frame every 15 frames

Comment: Do not use `-sameq`. See [`sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524).

Answer (score 1):

Try (according to http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Encoders)

*ffmpeg -i video.ym4 -vcodec libx264 **-g 15** -y -r 30 output.avi*

I think option `-sameq` (means "same quantizers") is not needed in your case.

Comment: this video is 10 sec and I want the frameput to be 30fps so we must get 300 frames. but when I used -g 15 the number of frames becomes more that 300, about1066, i want to keep them 300, so I used -vframes 300, the output frames becomes 326 so what to do